# convert html table to PrimeFaces datatable

Tags: primefaces, html-table

I want to convert html table to primeface datatable, I have converted some more table in my project but below code is bit complex so I need your help, here columns are created using different list and rows are from different list.

```
<table >
   <thead>
        <tr >
            <th style="width:45px;">Id</th>
            <th>#{msg['manage.relationship.type.name']}</th>

            <c:forEach items="#{manageRelationBean.languageList}" var="languageName" >
                <th>#{languageName}</th>
            </c:forEach>
            <th style="width:75px;">#{msg['manage.relationship.action']}</th>
        </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>
    <c:forEach items="#{manageRelationBean.languageRelList}" var="languageRelDTO">
<tr>
  <td>#{languageRelDTO.relationId}</td>
   <td>#{languageRelDTO.relationName}</td>
   <c:forEach items="#{languageRelDTO.languageList}" var="relationValues">
   <td>#{relationValues.relationValue}</td>
    </c:forEach>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</tbody>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Showcase example? http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableBasic.jsf

Here is something like your example, for the first few columns. Notice the ForEach within the datatable- This will allow dynamic columns like you have.

```
<h:form>  
    <p:dataTable var="languageRelDTO" value="#{manageRelationBean.languageRelList}">  

        <p:column headerText="Id">  
            <h:outputText value="#{languageRelDTO.relationId}" />  
        </p:column>  

         <p:column headerText="#{msg['manage.relationship.type.name']}">  
            <h:outputText value="#{languageRelDTO.relationName}" />  
        </p:column> 

        <c:forEach items="#{manageRelationBean.languageList}" var="languageName">
           <p:column headerText="#{languageName}" />
               <h:outputText value="#{languageRelDTO.languageList[languageName.index]}" /> 
           </p:column> 
        </c:forEach>

    </p:dataTable>  
</h:form>
```

Didn't test it, but you should get the idea.